# With Python how can I replace part of a path based on a piece that matches?

Tags: python

I have a path that looks like: `data/dev-noise-subtractive-250ms-1/1988/24833/1988-24833-0013.flac`

What I want to do is replace the second part, so that it's `data/dev-clean/1988/24833/1988-24833-0013.flac`. I can't guarantee anything about the second section, other than it starts with `dev-`.

I need to make it general-purpose, so that it'll work with any arbitrary stem, such as `train-`, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re` to match and replace it by:

```
def func(pattern, file):
    return re.sub(f'{pattern}[^/]+/', f'{pattern}clean/', file)


func('dev-', 'data/dev-noise-subtractive-250ms-1/1988/24833/1988-24833-0013.flac')
#data/dev-clean/1988/24833/1988-24833-0013.flac
func('train-', 'data/train-noise-subtractive-250ms-1/1988/24833/1988-24833-0013.flac')
#data/train-clean/1988/24833/1988-24833-0013.flac
func('train-', 'data/xxx/xxx/train-noise-subtractive-250ms-1/1988/24833/1988-24833-0013.flac')
#data/xxx/xxx/train-clean/1988/24833/1988-24833-0013.flac
```

Comment: But it won't always be `dev-` and I don't know it'll always be the second section

Comment: You have to have the exact pattern to do something like this, pattern or some logic that always work, and you can implement by that idea. Right now, your idea is not clear enough, how do you suppose to implement it?

Comment: That's my problem. I want a function so that I can pass any stem: `dev-`, `train-`, etc. And it will match the relevant portion of the path and replace with `*-clean`

Comment: is it allways clear that it will start with the stem, and is it allways the second directory? `/data/dev-whatever` `/data/train-something`

Comment: It's clear that it will always start with the stem, but not that it's the second directory

Comment: Can I somehow do it so that it's `anything-` without me having to specify what the `anything` is?

Comment: It's quite hard because let's say your path now is `data/dev-noise/sub-folder/company-name1988/24833.flac`. There are 3 patterns: `dev-noise`, `sub-folder`, `company-name1988`, how do I suppose to know which one to replace? If you are sure that it always has only one subfolder that contains `-` in it then I can do it, or any other kind of logic is possible, but it has to be specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace_second_part(path, with_what):
    parts = path.split('/')
    parts[1] = with_what
    return '/'.join(parts)
```

If you want this to be more portable (work under Windows, for example) using `os.path` is preferred.